# Как забрать роль у юзера discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Я пытаюсь забрать роль:

```
last_top = client.get_user(top_month)
role = get(client.get_guild(997438713770541127).roles, id = 1008811674695901316)
await client.remove_roles(last_top, role)
```

Но получаю ошибку:

```
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'remove_roles'
```

Пробую другим способом:

```
last_top = client.get_user(top_month)
role = get(client.get_guild(997438713770541127).roles, id = 1008811674695901316)
await last_top.remove_roles(role)
```

И опять получавю ошибку:

```
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'remove_roles'
```

Как это сделать??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
client.get_guild(сюда айди гильдии).get_member(айди юзера).remove_roles(обьект роли)
```